# Make skip button in review available even when at bottom at screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

I was going through review queue. I came across a review where I saw the answer first and went down to see question, I was not sure what to do so wanted to skip, but to skip the review I had to again go all the way to top.

Here is an animation to show what I mean (this was an example review):

[image: Animation showing the problem]

It would be better if we could skip even from bottom of screen or have a button which would take us all the way to top.

Just imagine cases where the question was even bigger.

Comment: I think the more important question is ... why is it set up so that the "Skip" button requires a horizontal scroll even at the top of the page?

Comment: You know, for a whole month I didn't even know there was a **skip** button (I accedentally discovered it by zooming out). And for a whole year after that I was skipping by zooming-out clicking the darn button and then zooming-in again. How the hell should we know you can even scroll to the right at the top of the page to get that stupid button when you're most of the time at the bottom when you need it?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me...

Comment: I could see this issue with 140% zoom. **Skip** button is visible with a normal zoom (100%).

Comment: Even with 100% zoom, if your browser is less than 1000 pixels wide, it will hide the skip button. Looks indeed like a bug.

Comment: Maybe the skip button should be moved to the front - so is the first button in the list?

Comment: My biggest concern is why would people use a zoom of 140%....

Comment: Side note: You can use "Home" to get to the top of the screen so you don't have to scroll all the way back up.

Comment: @Luuklag my zoom is 100% still I had that issue ,  ImportanceOfBeingErnest is right about what he said

Comment: It's bothered me for ages that the toolbar is just a bit too wide to show the Skip button when your browser is snapped to one half of a standard 1920x1080 monitor. I've been using a custom style to shrink it down a bit; it's a little ugly, but it works.

Comment: Maybe they don't want us to use the skip button. They said did, but then they found out what happens when people heed their advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this bug! It should be fixed on all sites as of this morning.

There were two small symptoms of the same bigger problem (the UI isn't responsive) here, I fixed both:

- We weren't updating the review bar's width as the page's width changed, but we were already listening to page changes for scroll.
- The action items didn't resize to fit on smaller than 1000px devices or devices with text scaling enabled.

Both cases seem okay to me now. Here's a new GIF:

[image: Animation showing the new flow]